# What's the best way to find "missing" values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Say there's a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5, 7,8, 10])
```

I want to find the "missing" numbers in it (6 and 9). My code to do this is:

```
li = []
low = int(min(df.values))
high = int(max(df.values))

for i in range(low, high+1):
    if i not in df.values:
        li.append(i)

print(li)
>>> [6, 9]
```

But if the dataframe is huge, this may take some time with a for loop. In my case, with a dataframe of length ~300k rows, its taking 162 seconds.

Is there a more efficient (vectorized?) way to do this?

Comment: do you know the set of numbers that should exist?

Comment: Yeah, serially from 1 to a threshold number (we can call it `m`).

Comment: What if the maximum value is missing?

Comment: `np.setdiff1d(np.arange(df[0].min(), df[0].max()), df[0])`?

Comment: @ user2285236 looks good to me, post it as answer... If you use OP's borders one can even see how really short that is: `np.setdiff1d(np.arange(1, m+1), df[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a list of the full range (assuming your bounds are represented in `df`), and then use `isin()` to find the difference.

```
m = 10
full = pd.Series(np.arange(1, m+1))

full[~full.isin(df[0])].values
# array([6, 9])
```

Comment: Yes! This reduced the running time from 162 seconds to 0.05 seconds!

Comment: Great!  Glad to be of help.

Comment: Did you try and measure the `np.setdiff1d` solution of user2285236, too? would be interesting to see how it compares.

Answer (score 0):

`df['didf'] = df[0] - df[0].shift(1)` will highlight gaps while values greater than 1 means a missing value